# .net core worker service HTTP Client PostAsync results in bad request (4000)

Tags: c#, .net-core, http-post, httpclient

```
public async Task<T1> PostAsync<T1, T2>(string url, T2 content)
{
    var requestUrl = CreateRequestUri(url);

    await AddHeaders();

    var request = CreateHttpContent<T2>(content);
    var response = _httpClient.PostAsync(requestUrl.ToString(), CreateHttpContent<T2>(content)).Result;
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T1>(data);
}


private HttpContent CreateHttpContent<T>(T content)
{
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content, MicrosoftDateFormatSettings);
    return new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
}
```

I am trying to invoke an API using HTTP Client (POST Async). I keep getting Bad request (400).
Please tell me how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: The error 400 is returned by the API you call. It is impossible to answer this question unless you provide detailed info on what is that you are calling. I would include that API name into the question title as well.

Comment: Check your header, probably application type.